# WooComerce, multiple terms from a URL query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Trying to get multiple terms to return all products associated with the specific taxonomy.

This will work fine as this only searches the single term
http://website.com/shop/?de_product_tag=test

This will work fine if the product contains both test and test-2 terms
http://website.com/shop/?de_product_tag=test,test-2

I am trying to achieve to show products that have those terms/tags, which works fine with an 'OR' for normal custom post types and blog, including custom taxonomies, but with WooCoomerce terms will only work with 'AND' relation, for 'OR' it will always return all results.

I have set up vars first:

```
 function de_custom_query_vars_filter($vars) {
    // normal categories
    $taxonomies = get_taxonomies();
    foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
        $vars[] .= 'de_' . $taxonomy;
    }
    $vars[] .= 'de_author';

    //product categories
    $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies('product');
    foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
        $vars[] .= 'de_' . $taxonomy;
    }
    return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'de_custom_query_vars_filter');
```

Then I have the WooCoomerce modified query which, as mentioned above 'OR' return all products and does not work, as it would for normal posts:

```
function de_modify_woo_query($query) {
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) {
        $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies('product');
        $tax_query = array('relation' => 'AND'); 
        foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
            if(get_query_var('de_' . $taxonomy)) {
                $terms = explode(',', get_query_var('de_' . $taxonomy));
                foreach($terms as $term) {
                    $tax_query[] = array(
                        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => array($term),
                        'operator' => 'IN'
                    );
                }
            }
        }

        if(!empty($tax_query)) {
            $query->set('tax_query', $tax_query);
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'de_modify_woo_query');
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tested if `get_query_var( 'de_' . $taxonomy )` is ever truthy? Also, it's possible that the main query `tax_query` already has a value, and the function overrides that. Better to isolate your taxonomy query parameters inside their own array: `$tax_query = $query->get( 'tax_query', array() ); $tax_query[] = array( 'relation' => 'AND', array( ... ), array( ... ) ); $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );`

Answer (score 0):

Woo Commerce doesn't accept multiple slugs in the query, in order to make it work the slug names had to be converted to ID's, and then multiple ID's work fine with the query.

Post, and custom post types do accept slugs fine with slugs from a taxonomy.